# Call Interactive Mode of HSPICE in Python

Tags: python, shell

I want to efficiently call HSPICE in Python. My final goal is speedup in my simulations (I have millions of it).

If I call HSPICE directly in shell:

```
hspice a1.sp                // method 1
hspice a2.sp
...
```

or

```
hspice -I -L xxx.txt       // method 2
```

Example of xxx.txt:

```
load a1.sp
run
load a2.sp
run
...
quit
```

The difference is that method 1 checks HSPICE's license each time, but method 2 uses interactive mode (`-I`) and it checks the license one time, so it is more time efficient.

I want to call HSPICE in Python to automate my simulation process:

Method 1 works, but method 2 has problem. In other words:

```
os.system('hspice yyy.sp')           // it works
```

However, when I use os.system, subprocess.call or subprocess.Popen, I cannot run it. For example,

```
args = ['hspice64', '-I', '-L', 'xxx.txt']
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

or

```
os.system('hspice64 -I -L xxx.txt')
```

It will stuck after `Hspice license have checked out`. The HSICE simulation is not done (thus, the whole simulation does not end) 
Does any one have any idea what is happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround can be writing a shell script to automate the interactive HSPICE calls.